# Replacing char in strings-changing elements in array

Tags: java, string

I have two goals:

1. Get two strings from user input. The first string must have an equal amount of vowels as the second consonants.
2. Replace every vowel in the second string with consecutive consonants from the first string.

Example:

```
Input1: kajak   
Input2: kajaka
Output: kkjjkk
```

I have managed to get the first goal working. However I have a problem with the second goal - changing letters in array.
I think the issue is in the array part `charSecond[i] =  charFirst[i]`  as the inputs have different sizes.

Edit: I forgot to add upper case in my vowels list-but just ignore it, I will fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zad2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Provide two strings: ");
            String firstString = scn.next();
            String secondString = scn.next();
            char charSecond[] = secondString.toCharArray();

            String firstWithoutVowels = firstString.replaceAll("[aeiouyAEIOUY]", "");
            String secondWithoutConsonants = secondString.replaceAll("[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz]", "");
            char charFirst[] = firstWithoutVowels.toCharArray();
            StringBuffer lengthOfFirst = new StringBuffer(firstWithoutVowels);
            StringBuffer lengthOfSecond = new StringBuffer(secondWithoutConsonants);
            if (lengthOfFirst.length() == lengthOfSecond.length()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < charSecond.length; i++) {
                    if (charSecond[i] == 'a' || charSecond[i] == 'e' || charSecond[i] == 'i' || charSecond[i] == 'o' || charSecond[i] == 'u' || charSecond[i] == 'y') {
                        charSecond[i] =  charFirst[i];
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < charSecond.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(charSecond[i]);
                }
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
            }

        }
        while (true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I just edited the post-now there is information about specific problem-substitution
letters in array. My question cannot be posted on Code Review-because its not optimization or security problem/review of working code (My answer is based on "What topics can I ask about here?" from Codereview site)  I want to say sorry about the wrong words I used in my post and now it should be proper.

Comment: Thank you for checking Code Review's rules AdamK. You are correct, this would be off-topic there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize int c = 0 before `if (lengthOfFirst.length() == lengthOfSecond.length())` condition

Replace the code(First for loop) like below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < charSecond.length; i++) {
    if (charSecond[i] == 'a' || charSecond[i] == 'e' || charSecond[i] == 'i' || charSecond[i] == 'o' || charSecond[i] == 'u' || charSecond[i] == 'y') {
        charSecond[i] =  charFirst[c];
        c++;
    }
}
```